# How can I get the programmes I use everyday to auto start at boot in the specified Workspaces?

Tags: 11.04, unity, workspaces, autostart

Is there a way I can have all the programmes I use everyday auto start in the correct workspaces?

Comment: what's your version?

Comment: If you are on 11.04 I think save session future is removed  You can check this topic http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1742263 The another way is to accomplish this task is to add all necessarily application on start-up.

Comment: I am on 11.04. I have updated my question, thanks.

Comment: @Achu that is one hell of a feature regression.

Comment: join me here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room

Comment: Why don't you just use suspend or hibernate instead of shutting down every day?

Comment: @psusi I don't shutdown everyday. Usually only at the weekends, but it is still 52 times a year I have to fiddle getting everything just right again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1)** Install [Compiz Settings Manager](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager).

**2)**  Open it (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type `ccsm`)

**3)** Go to "Windows Management"> "Place Windows" > "Fixed Window Placement"

**4)** At "Windows with fixed viewport" choose "New" and add the program you want to the viewport you want.

[image]

Comment: I have taken a look at this, but I am not clear on what it does. Any additional tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've edited the answer trying to clarify it for you ;-)